# Audio player shortcode not showing up when using variable

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, audio, term-meta

I am trying to call a custom term meta field in an audio shortcode that I have placed on a custom page that I am working on. The field contains a link to a .mp3 file that I have uploaded to my media library. I have an IF statement that will only show the audio player along with the text "Audio", if the field actually contains a link to an audio file. However, Nothing is showing up on the front end, even though there is a link in the field.

I did a var_dump on the field, and it outputted:

`string(95) "echo do_shortcode([audio src="http://www.foo.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/audio.mp3"])"`

Here is the code that I currently have in my functions.php:

```
function first_audio() {
                        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'firstb');
                        $result = "";
                        if (is_array($terms) || is_object($terms)){
                        foreach ($terms as $term) {
                            $term_id = $term->term_id;
                            $result .= 'echo do_shortcode([audio src="'.  get_term_meta($term_id, 'audioreco_64856', true)  .'"])';

                        }
                    }
                    if (!empty(get_term_meta($term_id, 'audioreco_64856', true))) {
                        return $result;}
                    }
```

And here is the code that I have on my page:

```
$first_audio = first_audio();
if (!empty($first_audio)) { ?>
<p><?php first_audio(); ?></p>
<?php }
    ?>
```

I also tried echoing `first_audio();` but that just echoed the whole link, just like the `var_dump` did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace following line

```
 $result .= 'echo do_shortcode([audio src="'.  get_term_meta($term_id, 'audioreco_64856', true)  .'"])';
```

with

```
$result .=  do_shortcode('[audio src="'.  get_term_meta($term_id, 'audioreco_64856', true)  .'"]');
```

Echo the result of function

```
<p><?php echo first_audio(); ?></p>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks! I tried that earlier, but I guess I messed up with the quotation marks...

Comment: One more question, If I would like to put something like this in front of  `do_shortcode` , how would I write it?  `<p>get_term_meta($term_id, 'short_27939', true)</p><br>`

Comment: add $result .= "<p>".get_term_meta($term_id, 'short_27939', true)."</p>"; above shortcode

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that if there are 2 taxonomies saved to the post, but only one of them has a link to an audio file, the audio player doesn't show up. Only id=f they both have audio files does it show up. Any idea why?